# How to create a text only info screen in Car Play?

Tags: swift, carplay

I would like to create a text only screen guiding users to configure the app on iPhone first, similar to "Unlock your iPhone to start CarPlay".

[image: Screenshot of 'Unlock your iPhone to start CarPlay']

Other apps show (and I don't have screenshots) some info like "When it is safe, use your phone to set up your app".

By the docs, you only have a few templates available:

- CPListTemplate
- CPGridTemplate
- CPTabBarTemplate
- CPTemplate (which has this comment: *You don’t use this class directly, or create your own subclasses. Instead, you must use one of the prebuilt templates, such as CPListTemplate or CPGridTemplate.*)

But it seems that none of them could have only a text message.

Does anyone has created this kind of info message? I wanna show something when users haven't set their account yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show an info message (without tabs) this way:

```swift
    let infoTemplate = CPInformationTemplate(
      title: "",
      layout: .leading,
      items: [CPInformationItem(title: "", detail: "When it is safe, use your phone to set up your app".localized())],
      actions: []
    )
    interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(infoTemplate, animated: false)
```

Which renders as:

[image: Screenshot in CarPlay emulator]

Comment: Have you tried the alert template?

Comment: Yes, but it is not allowed:

`
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported object <CPAlertTemplate: 0x600001375b80> <identifier: 0B8F7C4F-C118-4F10-8CF0-AD16A703A3A8, userInfo: (null), tabTitle: (null), tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to setRootTemplate:animated:completion:. Allowed classes: {(
    CPContactTemplate,
    CPTabBarTemplate,
    CPGridTemplate,
    CPMapTemplate,
    CPSearchTemplate,
    CPNowPlayingTemplate,
    CPPointOfInterestTemplate,
    CPListTemplate,
    CPInformationTemplate
)}'
`

Comment: Accordingly to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpalerttemplate), `CPAlertTemplate` is a modal:

_You must present alerts modally by calling the presentTemplate(_:animated:completion:) method available on your app’s instance of CPInterfaceController. The user dismisses the alert by pressing a button, or you can dismiss it by calling the interface controller’s dismissTemplate(animated:completion:) method._

Comment: Ah sorry, didn‘t know you wanted it as root

Comment: I do this as well, however it truncated after two lines of text. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a dynamic text with more than 2 lines...

Comment: Yeah, it truncates after 2 lines no matter what :-(